# Anylogic: Create text by Java with dynamic text content

Tags: anylogic

I want to create text using Java so that I can use codes to control how many shapetext to create and auto position them, but I want to link the text content to a dynamic value that is changing (e.g. a variable storing a parameter that varies during runtime). I am using the code below to create the text, however, when I replace "Test" with a variable, the text captures the value at the initial instance and remains a static value.

Is there any way to make the content dynamic or I can only write a function to actively refresh the text content?

Also, using a function to actively update the value makes the model run slower right? I compared the runs and observe that the model runtime is significantly slower.

```
col_Label_EQ.add(new ShapeText(SHAPE_DRAW_2D, 
               true, 
               0, 
               0, 
               0, 
               0, 
               white, 
               "Test", 
               new Font("SansSerif", 
                        Font.BOLD, 
                        10), 
               ALIGNMENT_CENTER));
```

presentation.add(col_Label_EQ.get(0));

[image]

Comment: what you did in text17 should work and update automatically...  nevertheless for any other case, you need to use setText()

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the setting of property is like the initial value, need function like setText() to change it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).